# WPF beginner: binding and templates

Tags: c#, wpf

I start now to work with wpf (Coming from Windows Forms) and I want now to create a little tool for playing around with wpf.
I understand that there are Bindings and templates, and understand what they do, and know that I have to fill the Window.DataContext and can the bind to this but for my example I don't get it all together, maybe someone can help me, to understand this better.

Models are

```
    class ViewModel
    {
        public List'Bank ListOfBanks { get; set; }
    }

    class Bank
    {
        public List'Account ListOfAccounts { get; set; }
    }

    class Account
    {
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public Decimal Money { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to do, is to have a dynamic list of (some nice blue) rectangles (Count = Number of Banks in ListOfBanks property) and in this Rectangle should be a grid with two columns (Description and Money properties) which should have as much as rows like there are Accounts in the ListOfAccounts property from the bank model.

What I know is

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

I know this is not much. And I know how to bind the grid columns against the Account properties, thats all.

It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Kind regards

Comment: You've got a lot of learning to do, it seems. Well beyond one or two questions and answers. Here is a great article that helped me get started with WPF and the MVVM pattern. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. It may be slightly advanced right now, but has additional links to very useful resources.

Comment: Thx, I know the MVVM pattern, but I will look at this article, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use a nested `ItemsCollection`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfBanks}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListOfAccounts.Count,StringFormat='Number of Accounts: {0}'}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAccounts}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Money,StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

ItemsControl is a basic repeating control -- if you want bells and whistles use `ListBox` (item selection) or `DataGrid` (sorting, grouping, automatic columns, etc).

Comment: Great, thats all I need, this answer helps me more than 100 tutorials.

Comment: Hi dbaseman, with your code I got an error message that I don't know.

"Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

The only things I change, the model Lists are ObservableLists.

Comment: @ChristianNeuß I think that error means you're trying to modify `ItemsControl.Items`...?  That's not allowed when the items are bound using `ItemsSource` -- instead you have to modify the source object directly, or cast `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` back to the source object type, and modify it that way.